# MSSQL - Return Select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to prepare procedure which will take 2 arguments (Int, string) If some row will exist in table I will get @dane = 1; and in the end I would like to select @dane but my procedure is not good. I can not use return @dane.

```
    USE [SS]
    GO

    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE [permission].[CheckSkill] 
(
    @SkillId INT, -- Identyfikator użytkownika 
    @Description NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @dana as int
    SET @dana = 0

    -- this is redundant:
    --SET @Description = RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(@Description,'')))

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM permission.UserXSkill Where permission.UserXSkill.SkillId = @SkillId)
    BEGIN
      SET @dana = 1;
    END

    SELECT @dana AS ID;
END
GO
```

Topic [closed] Thanks for help.

Comment: You have a typo - you declare the variable `@dana` then set the variable `@dane`. Also you must use `SET` or `SELECT` when assigning a value to a variable.

Comment: @Ed Harper I changed this. This was my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `SET` or `SELECT` when assigning a value to a variable.

`EXISTS` seems to serve the requirement in your `IF` block

The `@Description` parameter is unused and is redundant

```
USE [SS]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [permission].[CheckSkill] 
(
    @SkillId INT, -- Identyfikator użytkownika 
    @Description NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,

)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @dana as int
    SET @dana = 0

    -- this is redundant:
    --SET @Description = RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(@Description,'')))

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM permission.UserXSkill Where permission.UserXSkill = @SkillId)
    BEGIN
      SET @dana = 1;
    END

    SELECT @dana AS ID;
END
GO
```

Comment: Wait I have to check something

Comment: @Rafael-JuniorMVCDeveloper - this was taken from your original post. You need to check which schema the `UserXSkill` table resides in - try `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'UserXSkill'`. Replace `permission` with the value of the `TABLE_SCHEMA` column in the result set.